# for xml explicit dealing with namespace

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to query `explicit xml`. For that purposes I have to use `namespace`. Here is a simplified version:

```
SELECT 1                   as Tag,  
       NULL                as Parent,  
       i.SSN               as [SSN!1]
FROM   IRS_Table  as i
for xml explicit
```

But I want xml to look like this:

```
<irs:SSN>999-99-9999</irs:SSN>
```

Here is declaration of namespace in the beginning tags:

```
xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common"
```

How to revise script so that to see in output namespace?

**EDIT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">
        <irs:SSN>999-99-9999</irs:SSN>
    </n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query to include namespace into `for xml explicit`output.

```
SELECT 1                   as Tag,  
       NULL                as Parent,  
       i.SSN               as [irs:SSN!1],
       'urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common' as [irs:SSN!1!xmlns:irs] --namespace is here
FROM   IRS_Table as i
for xml  explicit
```

### Update

Probably easier is to use `for xml path` construction.

```
;with xmlnamespaces('urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common' as irs,
                    'blahblah' as n1,
                     default 'blahblah:blah' )
SELECT  
       null as [n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream], 
       ssn  as [n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream/irs:SSN]
FROM   IRS_Table as i
for xml path(''), elements, root
```

Comment: thank you. I  have added namespace in tag 1, and ssn in tag 2. Would you mind if you route me through the process of how to write query in order to achieve xml in EDIT above. n1: makes serious problems,  and how to add encoding field? Any help strongly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: THanks. I figured it out by myself